# Join two rows from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I currently have this query set-up:

```
SELECT 
  topic.content_id, 
  topic.title, 
  image.location 
FROM 
  mps_contents AS topic 
  INNER JOIN mps_contents as image 
    ON topic.content_id = image.page_id 
WHERE 
  topic.page_id = (SELECT page_id FROM mps_pages WHERE page_short_name = 'foo' ) 
  AND image.display_order = '1'
```

This is because I want to merge two rows from the same table in one row. This is a simplified setup of the table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| page_id | content_id | title | location | display_order |
-----------------------------------------------------------
|    1    |     200    |  Foo  |   NULL   |     200       |
|   200   |     201    |  Bar  | jpg.jpg  |      1        |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

And basically I want this result

```
---------------------------------
| content_id | title | location |
---------------------------------
|     200    |  Foo  | jpg.jpg  |
---------------------------------
```

So `Foo` is the 200th topic on page 1 (`Foo` is treated as a subpage and all its contents are stored in the same table) and `Bar` is its featured image (featured only because it is the 1st image)

The query above effectively joins the two rows (it returns my desired result) but it also returns an extra row corresponding to the original row for `Foo`, that is, the location is NULL.

I hope someone could help me prevent the query from returning that extra row.

Comment: I don't see how you are getting a row with null as the location with the example data you have above.

Comment: `Foo` actually has `NULL` for `location`.

Comment: Yes, I see that.  However there is no situation where you can join one row from that table to another row on that table and get a location of null with your select the way it is.

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, he can if he has a record of `(200,X,X,NULL,1)`.

Comment: Yep. That's what I am trying to figure out too. This is the description of the result set: `content_id` is `PRIMARY` and I see two rows having the same `content_id` in the result set. One has `location` set to 'jpg.jpg' and one is NULL.

Comment: Yes, however he is saying he is getting an extra because of the original row.  But that could not be the case.  The only way he might get the null is if one of the "images" doesn't have a location.

Comment: Content can still be unique for you to get a null value.  It's the page_id of your image that matches the Content_id of your topic would give you nulls.

Comment: @Stefan and $ypercube Thanks, I do have an entry of (200, X, X, NULL, 1) Now my problem is that the query is sorting out topics that do not have a feature image. This is something that I do not want. But thanks for the help!

Comment: So, you can either use `WHERE ... AND image.location IS NOT NULL` as Dan's suggestion. Or eliminate the extra entry.

Comment: Thanks its fixed now. My new problem is that sing LEFT or RIGHT OUTER JOIN does not seem to return rows that do not have a corresponding image entry for the topic. I really do want to return all topics and with their images if any. But thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WHERE ... AND location IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it still returns the extra row

Comment: It's topic.location or image.location that should not be null; put that in this clause. At 4AM I'm not going to try to figure out which alias corresponds to the row you want to eliminate.

Comment: You want topic to have a location of null, so you might be able to do image.location is not null

Comment: I don't see how this will solve it, as I don't think there is an issue in the first place.